# What is the difference between Eswaran and Sivaperuman?

Tags: upanishads, shiva-lingam, creation

Upanishads says Easwaran is our god and he has no shape and can't feel it on your  senses , we pray lord shiva is our first and almost god,he has shapes and lingam, 
did lord Shiva is creation of Easwaran,if so it is real and exists?

Comment: Lord Shiva took shape to grace us. Shiva Lingam is Arupa-Rupa (formless form) of the Parabrahman. It has a shape but not a shape like us. This shows that God is with and without shape both.

Comment: What are Eswaran and Sivaperuman? Which Upanishad says?

Comment: @Pandya Mundaka Upanishad  says, here is the link https://www.poornalayam.org/classes-recorded/upanishads/mundaka-upanishad/